# How to get drive letter by using serialnumber in windows powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

Below is the code i have used to get driveletter using the serialnumber

```
   Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_DiskDrive |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition 
    Where-Object VolumeSerialNumber -eq "66B78EE4" | Select-Object DeviceID
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition |
    Select-Object -Property SerialNumber

    Get-Volume
```

Please help this in getting the driveletter using serialnumber

Comment: Am I wrong or did you just forget a pipe after `Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition`??  ;-) ... and the part after `Select-Object DeviceID` is unnecessary if I'm not wrong.

Comment: This may help... gcim win32_volume | ? {$_.driveletter}| select driveletter,serialnumber ... both properties are found within the Win32_Volume class properties... if populated in your circumstance.